# How do i put tablayout below my title bar

Tags: android, xml

How to place Tablayout below the toolbar? It is giving me an error message and when i run it the toolbar doesn't show. But when i give the Tablayout alignbottom the toolbar then shows

Here is my xml file

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    tools:context="com.example.test.MainActivity">



    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar"/>


    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:id="@+id/nvd_act_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/cont_main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_act_main"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello World!" />
        </FrameLayout>


        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/lst_nav_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>


    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:background="#2480c1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_basic"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_basic_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tbl_basic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is the screen i created, the tablayout is in the bottom. I want it to be just below the toolbar. How do i do it? Thanks

[image: Here]

Here is the error message

@id/rel is not a sibling in the same RelativeLayout
Layout constraints in a given RelativeLayout should reference other views within the same relative layout (but not itself!)

Comment: "It is giving me an error message" - It would be helpful to people reviewing your question for you to post the error message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this 
 **change**
  android:layout_alignParentBottom="**true**" to   android:layout_alignParentBottom="**false**"

```
<RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="false"
        android:layout_below="@+id/app_bar "
        android:background="#2480c1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_gravity="center">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_basic"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_basic_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/tbl_basic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
        </RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it below the toolbar, then put it below the toolbar:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/rel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <include
        android:id="@+id/app_bar"
        layout="@layout/toolbar" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        android:id="@+id/footer"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:background="#2480c1"
        android:gravity="center">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tbl_basic"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        </android.support.design.widget.TabLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/lbl_basic_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_below="@id/tbl_basic"
            android:gravity="top"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/nvd_act_main"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/app_bar"
        >

        <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/cont_main_content"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent">

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/lbl_act_main"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center"
                android:text="Hello World!" />
        </FrameLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:id="@+id/lst_nav_drawer"
            android:layout_width="240dp"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:layout_gravity="start|left"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layoutManager="android.support.v7.widget.LinearLayoutManager" />
    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```